# Best way to solve SQL if Condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem 
this is my table item

```
Item |Begin | in01 | in02 | ..| in12 | out01 | out02 |..|out12 | Balance
A    | 100  | 10   | 20   | ..| 10   |   5   | 10    |..| 5    | 110
```

item A have begin qty 100 at first month, and balance qty at month 12 = 110
balance updating every month

i need to call a procedure to get data for every month report

```
sample for report for month 01
  Beginning| In |   Out | balance           
      100  | 10 |   5   | 105       

 sample for report for month 02
  Beginning| In |   Out | balance           
     105   | 20 |   10  |  115      
 sample for report for month 12
  Beginning    | In |   Out | balance           
balance month 11   | xx |   xx  |  11 + in - out
```

so beginning value  = balance last month
any way to make this stored procedure simple? not using a lot of 'IF'

it's better using case ?

need some idea.. thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use IF statements, have you considered redesigning your table? You can have 5 columns, Item, month, begin, in, and out. This way you have 5 columns instead of 27 columns and you can query exactly what you want easily. It is also much more efficient.

Comment: the problem is the table can't be redesign,

Answer (score 1):

u can used Case statement to avoid the if statement

```
select
case when beginning value = balance then 1st Option else 2nd Option as Test
from tblTest
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple conditions, it is better to use 'CASE', IF ELSE condition is only advisable to less conditions. like 2 to 3 conditions. If your conditional statements is more than 5 or 10, just use CASE WHEN to make your code more readable and easy to understand.

Regards.